# MergeSort Algorithm only returning half of the inputted array

Tags: java, mergesort

Having to learn different sorting methods for a school class but have encountered issues with coding MergeSort. Hoping someone can find what is causing the problem.

```
public static Movie[] mergeSortYears(Movie[] M)
{
    Movie[] toReturn = new Movie[M.length];
    if(M.length>1)
    {
        int length = M.length/2;

        Movie[] LeftAr = Arrays.copyOfRange(M,0,length-1);

        Movie[] RightAr = Arrays.copyOfRange(M,length,M.length-1);

        Movie[] Left = mergeSortYears(LeftAr);
        Movie[] Right = mergeSortYears(RightAr);

        return mergeYears(Left,Right);
    }
    return M;
}

public static Movie[] mergeYears(Movie[] LeftAR, Movie[] RightAR)
{
    Movie[] Left = LeftAR;
    Movie[] Right = RightAR;
    int Total = LeftAR.length + RightAR.length;
    int i,li,ri;
    Movie[] M = new Movie[Total];
    i = 0;
    li = 0;
    ri = 0;
    while(i< Total)
    {
        if((li < Left.length) && (ri<Right.length))
        {
            if(Left[li].Year < Right[ri].Year)
            {
                M[i] = Left[li];
                i++;
                li++;
            }
            else
            {
                M[i] = Right[ri];
                i++;
                ri++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(li >= Left.length)
            {
                while(ri<Right.length)
                {
                    M[i] = Right[ri];
                    i++;
                    ri++;
                }
            }
            if(ri >= Right.length)
            {
                while(li < Left.length)
                {
                    M[i] = Left[li];
                    li++;
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return M;
}
```

Yes I do admit it isn't exactly 'graceful' but it was the best I could do. But the issue arises when I call the function. I pass in an array containing 8 'Movie's (to pertain with the assignment) and it returns them properly sorted but only 4 of them. The thing that is really tripping me up is that I cannot figure out how it is losing those 4. It isn't like "The First 4" or "The Last 4" going missing. It is exactly the same 4 every time.

Movies do contain the 'Year' variable which contains their year of production, this is what they are sorted by in this instance. These do repeat in the majority of the movies but that doesn't appear to be causing the issue

(Can confirm it is the code presented causing the issue, earlier sections of this assignment had me sort with other methods and all those still work)

Comment: Your code is ugly (but you knew that). `Movie[] RightAr = Arrays.copyOfRange(M,length,M.length-1);` should be `Movie[] RightAr = Arrays.copyOfRange(M,length,M.length);`

Comment: EDIT: I'm an idiot, changed the wrong line. That just fixed everything.

Comment: [There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096?lang=en).